# Is there a way to ensure an Iterator correctly determines if the Linked List it corresponds to changes?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, iterator, dependencies

Maybe I did not word it correctly, but what I mean is this.

Say we have some Linked_List instance, call it list, and list has a basic insertion and functions for deleting it's own elements. Let's say to add an element to the list, it follows these rules...

1) It can be appended to the end of the list by calling it's functions directly (I.E Linked_List_Add)

2) Can be added to the list in a sorted order (I.E Based on a user-defined comparator callback)

3) Via an iterator, which allows it to store data anywhere (append or prepend).

An instance of Iterator, say iterator, contains a pointer to the Linked_List is corresponds to. Another pointer it has is one to the current node. Without further ado, let me present to you the dilemma I have.

The Linked_List can also remove nodes, and in fact the iterator never removes items itself, it just calls the Linked_List's remove function. So the rules for removal are as follows:

1) The Linked_List handles all removal and deletion.

2) The iterator will pass the current node to the Linked_List's removal/deletion function.

3) The Linked_List can delete nodes by index without having to rely on the current iterator.

No. 3 is the problem I'm having. I'd like to note that I have not currently finished this Linked List yet, nor it's iterator as I'm mostly thinking up potential problems before I move forward, and this one stands out the most.

Problems:

1) If the user removes the node that the iterator is currently on, then it would be impossible to call ->next or ->prev without potentially causing a segmentation fault, or at least undefined behavior.

2) If the user frees the linked list without making it NULL, then it will be impossible to assert whether or not the Linked List actually exists.

3) There is no way to currently update the iterator's current value or alert it that the list has been updated (besides for adding a byte/unsigned char as to whether or not it's been modified or not where the iterator will just reset the byte every time it accesses the linked list).

What would be the best way to handle this? Should I add a pointer to an iterator in the Linked List? However, then it starts as NULL (possible segmentation fault, unless there's some way to make static or private struct members to hide this, so it's only possible to retrieve it with an iterator constructor which returns a new instance of iterator if one currently does not exist, or the currently created one). Alternatively, doing so would ensure that there is only one iterator per list rather than the possibility of creating multiple.

Maybe instead I should create an unsigned char to determine whether or not the Linked_List has been changed, this would be the minimal option, since it's only one byte extra instead.

A basic template of what I'm attempting is here.

```
/* Very simple, minimal node. */
struct Node {
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
    void *item;
};

/* Linked_List contains the user-defined (or default) callbacks for deleting an
   item, or comparing two items. */
struct Linked_List{
    /// The very first node.
    Node *first;
    /// The very last node.
    Node *last;
    /// The current size of the linked list.
    size_t size;
    /// Callbacks and function pointers
};

/* Iterator will contain function pointers for ease of use. */
struct Iterator {
    /// The linked list to iterate through.
    Linked_List *list;
    /// The current node in the list the iterator is on.
    Node *current;
    /// Function pointers
};
```

Comment: why a seperate iterator struct though instead of a Node *current; element in Linked_List? And I don' think the problems can be solved in any convenient way

Comment: You know... that is a very good question. I'm trying to remember my original reason myself, but the only answer I can think of is that I'm used to using an iterator in Java for lists. I suppose I'd be much better off having the linked list double as an iterator

Comment: I remember now, it was so to open up the possibility of custom iterators. I foolishly attempted to combine both a Single, Double and Tree list into one, so the iterator would have either been configured depending on what type of list chosen. I suppose there's no point in it now.

Comment: Well, I suppose you could extend the list to keep track of its iterators, use a callback function, or add a list of iterators in the list... not very convenient I guess, but the only thing I can come up with right now.

Comment: Probably better off if I remove it entirely, truth be told. I made it and I can't think of a valid reason to keep it, only if the linked list was so incredibly large, like millions of items, that you would need multiple to concurrently search it, but that's the problem for the Linked List itself to handle rather than the user.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure after shifting things around. While true the Linked List can double as an iterator, the amount of functions (and function pointers) increase largely. I.E Remove variants: Remove at Index, Remove Item passed, Remove Current. Add variants: Append, Prepend, Add sorted, Add to End, Add to Beginning, etc. Due to lack of overloading, they start to build up rather fast.

Comment: actually not that much. You don't need a function for every possiblity, some of the functionallies could be replicated with 2 function calls of the basic functions anyway. Here's how I usually do it: https://github.com/pfannkuchengesicht/passgen/blob/master/list.h

Worked fine so far.

Comment: The advantage of having a formal iterator type that is separate from and initialized/created for a specific list is that the list can contain a record of the active iterators. It could then use the presence of any iterators to ban modifications, or it could analyze the iterators to see if the modification will affect any of the iterators. It's a bit heavy-weight, but possible. You might encode forward and reverse iterators in a single structure, so the forward iterators start at the beginning and traverse to the end, whereas reverse iterators start at the end and traverse to the start.